# How to update View of Window 1 when Event happen in Window 2 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two Windows 1 and 2. Window 2 takes data from User and then calls the method of Window 1 and in this method it updates the values of ViewModel of Window 1. But updates value not reflecting in Window 1.
Following is my code
MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel() { }

    private LoadCurrentViewModel _LoadCurrentVM;
    public LoadCurrentViewModel LoadCurrentVM { get { return _LoadCurrentVM; } set { _LoadCurrentVM = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LoadCurrentVM"); } }
    private LoadingHistoryTopView _LoadHistoryTopActiveVM = new LoadingHistoryTopView();
    public LoadingHistoryTopView LoadHistoryTopActiveVM { get { return _LoadHistoryTopActiveVM; } set { _LoadHistoryTopActiveVM = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LoadHistoryTopActiveVM"); } }
    private LoadCurrentViewModel _LoadCurrentViewModelData = new LoadCurrentViewModel();
    public LoadCurrentViewModel LoadCurrentViewModelData { get { return _LoadCurrentViewModelData; } set { _LoadCurrentViewModelData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LoadCurrentViewModelData"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }


}
```

Window 2 as follows
public partial class Scanner : Window
    {

```
    //public LoadCurrentViewModel LoadCurrentViewModelData { get; set; } = new LoadCurrentViewModel();
    LoadCurrentBetween objMain = new LoadCurrentBetween();
    LoadingHistory objLoadHistory = new LoadingHistory();
    MainViewModel _MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    LoadHistoryUC objLoad = new LoadHistoryUC();
    public Scanner()
    {
        DataContext = _MainViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }                                                                 
     private void PaintScan(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        //Insert Scanned values to db
        DbOperations.InsertScanHistory(_MainViewModel.LoadCurrentViewModelData.Part, Convert.ToInt32(_MainViewModel.LoadCurrentViewModelData.NoofHook), 2, _MainViewModel.LoadCurrentViewModelData.Date, _MainViewModel.LoadCurrentViewModelData.Time);
        //objLoad.PopulateHistory(objLoad);
        objLoadHistory.PopulateHistory();
        MessageBox.Show("PaintScan Done");
    }
```

Window 1 code as follows

```
  public partial class LoadingHistory : Window
{
    public List<LoadingHistoryModel> LoadhistoryVM = new List<LoadingHistoryModel>();
    public LoadingHistoryTopView LoadhistorytopVM = new LoadingHistoryTopView();
    public MainViewModel _MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    public LoadingHistory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _MainViewModel;
        PopulateHistory();
    }
    public void PopulateHistory()
    {
        LoadhistoryVM = DbOperations.GetLoadHistory();
        if (LoadhistoryVM.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers.Count(); i++)
            {
                switch (LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].LinePosition)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //LoadhistoryVM[i].IsLoaded = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        PainttopView paint = new PainttopView();
                        paint.Hookno = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber;
                        paint.LinePosition = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].LinePosition;
                        paint.isEmpty = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber == 0 ? true : false;
                        if (!paint.isEmpty)
                            paint.ImgSource = "/Views/Image/Bluering.png";
                        else
                            paint.ImgSource = "/Views/Image/RedStop.png";
                        _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Paint.Add(paint);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BaketopView bake = new BaketopView();
                        bake.Hookno = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber;
                        bake.LinePosition = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].LinePosition;
                        bake.isEmpty = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber == 0 ? true : false;
                        if (!bake.isEmpty)
                            bake.ImgSource = "/Views/Image/Bluering.png";
                        else
                            bake.ImgSource = "/Views/Image/RedStop.png";
                        _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Bake.Add(bake);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        CooltopView cool = new CooltopView();
                        cool.Hookno = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber;
                        cool.LinePosition = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].LinePosition;
                        cool.isEmpty = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber == 0 ? true : false;
                        if (!cool.isEmpty)
                            cool.ImgSource = "/Views/Image/Bluering.png";
                        else
                            cool.ImgSource = "/Views/Image/RedStop.png";
                        _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Cool.Add(cool);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //LoadhistoryVM[i].IsUnloaded = true;
                        break;
                }

                _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Hooks.Add(LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber);
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.HookNumber = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].HookNumber;
                    _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.LinePosition = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].LinePosition;
                    _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.PartNumber = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].PartNumber;
                    _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Workorder = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].Workorder;
                    _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Date = LoadhistoryVM[0].GroupPartNumbers[i].Date;
                }
            }
        }           
        DataContext = _MainViewModel;
    }
}
```

Window1.xaml

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Margin="10">
                <Grid Background="White" DataContext="{Binding LoadHistoryTopActiveVM}">..........
```

I have used aggregator subscribe approach too but problem is still the same model is updating but not reflecting in View.
Subscribe in Window 1 as follows

```
public FillLoadCurrent(EventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        }

        public void Handle(SignalMessage obj)
        {
            _MainViewModel.LoadHistoryTopActiveVM.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
            //PopulateHistory();
            Console.WriteLine("I'm a car and a guard is telling me to stop!");
        }
```

Window 2 is publishing

```
 var eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        var car1 = new FillLoadCurrent(eventAggregator);
        var car2 = new FillLoadCurrent(eventAggregator);
        var car3 = new FillLoadCurrent(eventAggregator);
        var Event = new EventEmitter(eventAggregator);

        Event.SignalLoadCurrent(_MainViewModel.LoadCurrentViewModelData, objMain);
```

Model is updating but not reflecting in UI
please help

Comment: You are not sharing the same instance of your MainViewModel in both Windows. 

        ``public MainViewModel _MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();``

This line is found in both windows. So one of your models is being updated but not both. 

I think it would be better to create two independent ViewModels for your two windows and use a MessageBus or something similar to communicate between them.

For example ViewModel 1 tells ViewModel 2, that it needs to be updated.

Comment: @feal thanks for you suggestion, can you tell me how to share common instance across Windows

Comment: you could implement singleton pattern on MainViewModel

Comment: Sorry i dont understand, what this program is doing actually. Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @feal it opens two separate windows of same project and when user enter some data in first window second window have to show data related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i read your code again. This is a way how to do it. When you open your second window. pass your viewmodel instance to it and use it there as DataContext as well.

Example:

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
  // Capsulate DataContext to MainViewModel
  public MainViewModel MainViewModel
  {
    get => this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
    set => this.DataContext = value;
  }

  public Window1()
  {
    this.InitializeComponents();
    // Create new MainViewModel and set DataContext (in property)
    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
  }

  private void OpenWindow2()
  {
    // pass current MainViewModel to Window2
    var window2 = new Window2(this.MainViewModel);
    window2.Show();
  }
}

public class Window2 : Window
{
  public MainViewModel MainViewModel
  {
    get => this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
    set => this.DataContext = value;
  }

  public Window2(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
  {
    // set MainViewModel to instance passed from MainWindow
    this.InitializeComponents();
    this.MainViewModel = mainViewModel();
  }
}
```

I hope you get the idea and that helps.